# How and why I can't override related manager method on django?

Tags: python, django, orm, entitymanager

I have this manager:

```
class ConfigValueManager(models.Manager):

    def get(self, key):
        config_value = self.filter(key=key).first()
        if config_value:
            type_caster = locate(config_value.type)
            return type_caster(config_value.value)
        return config_value

    def set(self, key, value):
        self.filter(key=key).update(value=value)

    def set2(self, key, value):
        qs = self.filter(key=key)
        if qs:
            qs.update(value=value, type=type(value).__name__, company=self.instance)
        else:
            self.create(key=key, value=value, type=type(value).__name__, company=self.instance)
```

the problem is that I can't overwrite `set`. The method is still coming from the parent, even though I've created `set` on the child. Funny thing is that `get` and `set2` are fine. Even `add` which isn't in my example can't be overridden.

My question is how can I overwrite `set` and why this happens?

Comment: How are you using this? And what behaviour are you seeing, exactly? The base Manager class doesn't have a `set` method.

Comment: yes it have: https://github.com/django/django/blob/83b04d4f88dd65ae630a45385de34e275899dc41/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L702

And the base Manage class doesn't have `set2` and I can define it, that doesn't matter.

I just want to define some methods but looks like some of them have a constraint that unable me to override them.

Comment: But that's why I asked how you are using it. That's a related manager, which is constructed dynamically, not a standard manager. Once again,  *how* are you using this in your class?

Comment: @Dainel Roseman, like this: https://gist.github.com/aj07mm/bbb760ce4ae0fc1e5f7d8cf7b6ded258

Answer (score 0):

I add some details on why it's not easily possible, because I struggled on the same issue. 
`set`, like `add` or `create`, are overridden in the dynamically created `RelatedManager`, as we can see in the [django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L728). This `RelatedManager` actually uses our manager as a [super class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L559) that's why your `get` and `set2` methods can used, but it does not help for overridden methods.

This manager is created in the `ReverseManyToOneDescriptor.related_manager_cls` cached property. In the example on your github snippet, `Company.config_values` is an instance of this `ReverseManyToOneDescriptor`.

I'll show an example on how to override the `set` method, by making some assumptions on your code, because it misses some definitions (like the `Company` model, the `ForeignKey` field inside `FooConfigValue`.)

I don't advise to use it, as it's absolutely not robust against django changes, and I didn't do any test, it just serves as a proof on how `RelatedManager` instances are created 
Add this at the end of the example code and it should work

```py
def modify_related_manager_set(model_cls):
    # model_cls = Company here, and config_values is the related field name
    reverse_descriptor = model_cls.config_values
    base_set = reverse_descriptor.related_manager_cls.set

    def custom_set(*args, **kwargs):
        print("in my custom set")
        return base_set(*args, **kwargs)

    reverse_descriptor.related_manager_cls.set = custom_set
# do this call after all the models have been created
# e.g. after defining FooConfigValue
 modify_related_manager_set(Company)
```

And you should now see the `in my custom set` being printed.

I know this doesn't help much, but at least it helped understand how related fields work

Answer (score -1):

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet


class PersonQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def set(self, slug, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(slug=slug).update(**kwargs)


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

    objects = PersonQuerySet.as_manager()
```

## tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from core.models import Person

class TestSet(TestCase):
    def test_just_update_records_with_the_same_slug(self):
        Person.objects.create(slug='batman', name='John')
        Person.objects.create(slug='batman', name='Connor')
        Person.objects.create(slug='bruce', name='Ill be back')

        Person.objects.set('batman', name='###')

        expected_value = 2
        result = Person.objects.filter(name='###').count()

        self.assertEqual(result, expected_value)
```

## github example

https://github.com/luivilella/django-test-manager